# Does a standard exist for variable names used left of a require()?

Tags: node.js, require

A simple question: I do not understand if a standard exists for variable names to be used left of `require()`'s, and if it does, what does it require: Uppercase or lowercase (camelcase) variable names?

To be clearer:

```
myImage = require('./image');
```

or

```
MyImage = require('./image');
```

?

I ask since required modules always return objects, so they can be used as Classes *or* Objects...

Comment: NodeJS is server sided *javascript*, so following standard JS practices (camelCase) would be the "norm" for things like variable naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no requirement for the name of any variable in JavaScript except the rules defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/2039244). Some JavaScript frameworks have naming conventions, but these do not borrow from any native JavaScript behaviour.

However, usually you will see JS code with classes having capitalised pascal-case names (`MyClass`) and everything else is camel-case (`anObject`). I suggest that you abide this general standard in your own code so that it is easier for others to reason with.

This means that when you `require` you should employ the above naming convention according to what it is that you are `require`ing:

```
// CommonJS
let MyClass = require('./MyClass')
let utilMethod  = require('./MyClass/utilMethod')

// ES6
import MyClass, { utilMethod } from 'MyClass';
```

Comment: I'm speaking about *Node.js*... And asking for *conventions*... I know javascript syntax does not require any specific case...

Comment: @MarcoS no language "requires" specific case, but seeing as NodeJS is still JS, it is best to adhere to standard JavaScript naming conventions. I could easily use snake_case in JS, or camelCase in python and it will still work, but it's not language convention.

Comment: `pascal-case` names for classes and `camel-case` for objects you are speaking of in your answer: these are the conventions I'm speaking about... My question could be rephrased as "Should I consider the return value from a require as a Class, or as an Object, or it depends by the module?"

Comment: Depends on the module. could be a class, a function, an object, array, string, or even undefined.

Comment: @MarcoS Yes, it depends on the module.